# Is there analogue for RxJava Subject in Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

In 2020 a lot of android developers are talking about Kotlin Coroutines. I'm trying to understand it and how coroutines can help me in my project.

So my question: **is there analogue in Coroutines for RxJava Subjects?** (As minimum for `PublishSubject`).

What I want - I use `PublishSubject` for sending events from `ViewModel` to my `View`. I subscribe to eventsSubject on `onStart()` method and dispose on `onStop()` method.

So the minimal requirements for Kotlin Coroutines analogue are:

- Easy testing (I use TestSubscriber and it is awesome)
- I want to send events without buffering
- Easy to subscribe/unsubscribe

There is sample of my use case:

ViewModel:

```
abstract class AbsStateViewModel<State, Event> : AbsViewModel() {
    private val stateSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<State>()
    private val eventSubject = PublishSubject.create<Event>()

    protected val requireState: State
        get() = stateSubject.value!!

    fun getStateObservable(): Observable<State> = stateSubject

    fun getEventObservable(): Observable<Event> = eventSubject

    protected fun sendEvent(event: Event) {
        eventSubject.onNext(event)
    }

    protected fun setState(state: State) {
        stateSubject.onNext(state)
    }
}
```

And usages:

```
viewModel.getEventObservable() // called on onAttach()
            .subscribe(
                    this::handleEvent,
                    this::defaultHandleException
            )
            .disposeOnDetach() // my extensions
```

Comment: AFAIK a `Channel` is the typical replacement for a `Subject`, particularly in cases like this. Alternatively, use `LiveData`, as you could have done here, reserving coroutines/RxJava for deeper layers (viewmodel <-> repository, etc.).

Comment: By default LiveData store last item (like BehaviourSubject) and I don't like workaround for LiveData. I use LiveData for state (view need to obtain current state when subscribes to viewModel) and I'm looking for Subject replacement but still I don't see it

Comment: Then, use a `Channel`.

Comment: Here is a set of subject implementations mirroring RxJava ones: https://github.com/akarnokd/kotlin-flow-extensions#publishsubject

Comment: Have you found an example solution?  I am wondering the same.

Answer (score 4):

yes in coroutines there are the analogue of rx subjects, the channels. If you want to reproduce the behavior of  `PublishSubject` you can use the  `BroadcastChannel` else if you want to reproduce the behavior of  `BehaviorSubject` you can use the  `ConflatedBroadcastChannel`.

Comment: Yep, but it's still under @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi (

Comment: Do you can provide sample how can I subscribe and unsubscribe to the Channel from View? Remember that events count can be from 0 to N, so I don't know events count

Comment: Yes i know, i'm waiting for next kotlin release to use them. You can use them in ui with lifecycleScope:  `lifecycleScope.launch { for (value in channel) {  ... do something } }` . The `lifecycleScope` closes automaticaly the channel when the ui will die.

Answer (score 2):

Since Coroutines 1.4.0 (Nov 2020), `SharedFlow` and `StateFlow` are the new equivalents for RxJava `Subjects`.

`PublishSubject` can be replaced with `MutableSharedFlow()`.
`ReplaySubject` can be replaced with `MutableSharedFlow(Int.MAX_VALUE)`
`BehaviorSubject` can be replaced with `MutableStateFlow()`, but with a special caveat!

`MutableStateFlow` will ignore equal items. It is the same as `BehaviorSubject().distinctUntilChanged()` If you want equal values to be emitted, you'll need a special `MutableSharedFlow`

```
fun <T> newBehaviorFlow(init: T) = MutableSharedFlow<T>(
  replay = 1,
  onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST,
).also { it.tryEmit(init) }
```

For your use case,

```
abstract class AbsStateViewModel<State, Event> : AbsViewModel() {
    private val stateSubject = newBehaviorFlow<State>()
    private val eventSubject = MutableSharedFlow<Event>()

    protected val requireState: State
        get() = stateSubject.first()

    fun getStateObservable() = stateSubject.asStateFlow()

    fun getEventObservable() = eventSubject.asSharedFlow()

    protected fun sendEvent(event: Event) {
        eventSubject.tryEmit(event)
    }

    protected fun setState(state: State) {
        stateSubject.tryEmit(state)
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
viewModel.getEventObservable() // called on onAttach()
            .onEach(this::handleEvent)
            .catch(this::defaultHandleException)
            .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope or viewModelScope) // from lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1
```